# How is multiple variable control done for preg match inside of if conditional?

Tags: php, regex, if-statement, pattern-matching, preg-match

I check the inputs that come with the post method. But this if conditional code not work. Edit: Else falls on his block

Is JavaScript

```
$(".inputonlytext").keypress(function(e) {

    var key = e.keyCode;
    if ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 33 && key <= 47) || (key >= 58 && key <= 64) || (key >= 91 && key <= 96) || (key >= 123 && key <= 127)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    /*if (e.which === 32)
        return false; */
    //var text = $(this).val();
    //$(this).val(text.replace(" ", ""));

});
```

Is Input

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control inputonlytext" maxlength="50" required="required">
<input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control inputonlytext" maxlength="50" required="required">
```

Is PHP;

```
if($_POST["name"] !== null && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/', $_POST["name"]) && $_POST["surname"] !== null && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/', $_POST["surname"])){
            //true for my application logic. (think like a reverse)
}else{
            //false for my application logic. (think like a reverse)
}
```

Comment: What are some sample `name` and `surname` POST parameters for which your if statement appears to be failing?

Comment: oh sorry Else falls on his block.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Your code looks fine. If it's not working, please give sample data that causes unexpected results and explain what the expected result is.

Comment: The data coming with the Post method falls into the else block, although it carries the pattern and other conditions.

Comment: I updated the question with other data.

Comment: Code not working according to current tests "$_POST["name"] !== null".

Comment: try to validate with `ctype_alnum`

Comment: You should use `preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/', $_POST["name"]) === 1`

Comment: Does it verify that the variable is not empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your interest.

Here is an alternative;

I used

```
$_POST["name"] !== null
```

instead of

```
isset($_POST["name"])
```